# How to get a consolidated list of test results in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

Using the following in my TestNG Selenium Webdriver test XML,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="ConfigurationListenerExample Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.MyConfigListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="ConfigurationListenerExample1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.MyConfigListenerExample1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="ConfigurationListenerExample2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.MyConfigListenerExample2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="ConfigurationListenerExample3">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.MyConfigListenerExample3" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I get reports corresponding to each class being tested. If possible, how can I obtain a single test report for the test suite instead of individual ones? Thanks.

Comment: how do you trigger your test suite? most probably you will be specifying each test name separately.

Comment: Each class listed in the XML contains test methods; HTML reporter gives me a report for each class ie. 3 separate test HTML reports in the above case and I would like to have just one report listing all.